# PYSPARK : Update value in a row with another row value based on condition?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to update some columns based on unique ticket id(groupby) on following conditions and return the particular record:

1.Whenever the status is closed - that particular record **run_date only** needs to get update in **closed_time column** of the **closed status record** based on unique ticket id.

2.Whenever the status is In-progress - that particular record **run_date only** needs to get update in **inprogress_time column** of the **closed status record** based on unique ticket id.(Only run_date will get update in the inprogress_time of the closed status record).

3.Whenever the status is cancelled -that particular record run_date only needs to get update in **cancelled_time column** of the **cancelled status record** based on unique ticket id.

`INPUT DATAFRAME`

```
Id  type  inprogress_time  closed_time  cancelled_time  status    Source_system   Run_date
11  TRUCK   NAN            NAN           NAN            Created     LIBERATE    1/9/2021 12:00
11  TRUCK   NAN            NAN           NAN            In_Progress LIBERATE    1/9/2021 12:00
11  TRUCK   NAN            NAN           NAN            Closed      LIBERATE    8/9/2021 19:21
22  TRUCK   NAN            NAN           NAN            Cancelled   LIBERATE    3/9/2021 15:08
33  TRUCK   NAN            NAN           NAN            Created     LIBERATE    4/10/2021 15:08
33  TRUCK   NAN            NAN           NAN            In_Progress LIBERATE    4/10/2021 15:08
33  TRUCK   NAN            NAN           NAN            Closed      LIBERATE    5/10/2021 15:08
```

`EXPECTED RESULT(OUTPUT DATAFRAME)`

```
Id  type    inprogress_time  closed_time    cancelled_time     status       Source_system  run_date
11  TRUCK   1/9/2021 12:00  8/9/2021 19:21   NAN               Closed        LIBERATE  8/9/2021 19:21
22  TRUCK   NAN             NAN              3/9/2021 15:08    Cancelled     LIBERATE  3/9/2021 15:08                 
33  TRUCK   4/10/2021 15:08 5/10/2021 15:08  NAN               Closed        LIBERATE  5/10/2021 15:08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `pivot` is more efficient.

```py
df.groupBy('Id', 'type', 'Source_system').pivot('status').agg(f.first('Run_date')) \
  .withColumnRenamed('Cancelled',   'cancelled_time') \
  .withColumnRenamed('Closed',      'closed_time') \
  .withColumnRenamed('In_Progress', 'inprogress_time') \
  .drop('Created') \
  .withColumn('status', f.expr('''
      CASE WHEN cancelled_time  is not null THEN 'Cancelled'
           WHEN closed_time     is not null THEN 'Closed'
           WHEN inprogress_time is not null THEN 'In_Progress'
      ELSE 'Created' END ''')) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+---+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
|Id |type |Source_system|cancelled_time|closed_time    |inprogress_time|status   |
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
|33 |TRUCK|LIBERATE     |null          |5/10/2021 15:08|4/10/2021 15:08|Closed   |
|11 |TRUCK|LIBERATE     |null          |8/9/2021 19:21 |1/9/2021 12:00 |Closed   |
|22 |TRUCK|LIBERATE     |3/9/2021 15:08|null           |null           |Cancelled|
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thankyou!! Very helpful.. It works for me. But If I want to add specific run_date column also to the output dataframe means what should I do? I tried by adding the run_date column in groupby..but it is returning another column which I don't want. So I need to include one more column with specific rundate to the output dataframe. Can you pls help me on this.

Comment: What does the specific means? and by what logic? I didn't get it what you exactly mean. If you need more, modify your question or post another one.

Comment: Please check the updated question. Atlast , I also want to add run_date column. Can you pls help me on this... I tried by adding run_date in groupby but that gives another row which I don't want @Lamanus

Comment: I tried by adding run_date column in groupby, but not worked.                                  EXAMPLE: df.groupBy('Id', 'type', 'Source_system','Run_date').pivot('status').agg(f.first('Run_date'))

Comment: I think you cannot simply add it by groupby, but later get back from the *_time columns. For ex, `.withColumn('Run_date', f.coalesce('cancelled_time', 'closed_time'))`.